# What software would you recommend for making a simple list-creating app for iOS and Android?

Tags: development-environment, mobile-development

So, my aunt wants me to make an app to help people create lists and be more organized. It would also have pre-made lists and tips that occasionally appear. We both want it to be for iOS and Android. Does anyone have recommendations for what software I could use to create something like that? One other thing to note: I can't use XCode because I'm not a mac user. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Honestly, if you're asking that you're probably in over your head, but Xamarin would be what I'd tell ya.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is on-topic on Stack Overflow. You might be able to find an answer on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question depends a lot in preference and personal opinion... 
Unity is my personal favorite tool to deploy in multiple platforms and even if its a game engine I have used it for simple user interface aplications with very little effort and bug count... the withdrawals are that you use a "lot" to make so little... the whole physics engine does nothing and the apk weigths at least 20Mb ... but its a very simple tool that could do the job in a couple of days having little experience and thats what i like about it.... theres also Xamarin C# , Android studio... React.. Depends a lot on your liking...and personal preference.

Comment: I am trying Xamarin right now. I tried using it at one point and couldn't figure it out but now they have tutorials and so I don't have to rely on Microsoft's docs.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would go for [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) it is a mobile apps building framework using only **Javascript**!

Here is a showcase of real-world apps using RN: [Who's using React Native?](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase)